# iOS - cocoapods not updating

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I have my own pod that i have uploaded to cocoa.
I have uploaded new lined of code , i can see them in the repo , i can see them in the pod that is in the project but still they aren't executed.

Pod spec:
[image]

pod new code lines from the podspec:
[image]

any idea?

pod new code lines in the repo:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For now, I am doing `rm -rf Pods` and then `pod install`.
That fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure that you have release new version of pod in Cocoapods with the updated code.
- In your iOS Application, run the following commands to get the latest version of pod:

  ```bash
  pod repo update
  pod update
  ```

Comment: The version is the same.
Did :
git tag 1.1.8
git push --tags
and i can see that it install this version

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the git commit that has the change you want is tagged with the version specified in the podspec.  In this case -- `1.1.8`.

Comment: The version is the same. Did : git tag 1.1.8 git push --tags and i can see that it install this version

Comment: Do a `pod cache clean` if you had a previous incarnation of 1.1.8 installed locally.

Comment: pod cache clean LamdaConnectivityManager

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 10 and the new build system has bugs when it comes to development pods. Try switching your project to using the legacy build system, this has helped me in several projects.

Comment: Interesting, can you guide me how?

Comment: Simple: Go to File / Workspace Settings and change "Build System" to "Legacy Build System". You'll see a small hammer-like icon in the top status bar after that.